# UIWindows class subviews method missing

Tags: iphone, uiview, uikit, uiwindow

Im just going through a video tutorial on swaping views.

see code below please:

NSArray *subs = [window subviews];

The "window subviews" code simply returns the views into the array subs.

But I checked the UIWindow class and I cannot find the property "subviews". Please help, no point my watching video tutorials if I dont understand the code.

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

UIWindow inherits from UIView. UIView has the [subviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/subviews) property.